# How to remove the Blue and gray annotions of mapbox in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapbox

How Can I Remove the user location icon defaultly shown by the map box

```
 - (MGLAnnotationView *)mapView:(MGLMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MGLAnnotation>)annotation{
if (mapView.userTrackingMode == MGLUserTrackingModeFollow) {
    return  nil;
}
return Nil;
}
```

Hi, I have implemented this code.And I viewdidloadTried this

```
    mapView.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
mapView.backgroundColor  = [UIColor clearColor];
[mapView.attributionButton setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

But still Showing ...

Comment: show your tried code.

Comment: R u working with google maps, if yes use this function  yourMapView.myLocationEnabled = false

Comment: I. have updated my code @Anbu.karthik

Comment: I am working with mapbox @iOS

Comment: Try this mapView.showsUserHeadingIndicator = false

Comment: Still it showing @iOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mapbox documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/help/first-steps-ios-sdk/)

> you have configured your application’s location permissions, display the device’s current location on the map by setting the **showsUserLocation** property on the map view to **NO**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];


MGLMapView *mapView = [[MGLMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
mapView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[mapView setCenterCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.74699, -73.98742)
                   zoomLevel:9
                    animated:NO];
[self.view addSubview:mapView];


mapView.styleURL = [MGLStyle satelliteStreetsStyleURL];


// Add a point annotation
MGLPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MGLPointAnnotation alloc] init];
annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.77014, -73.97480);
annotation.title = @"Central Park";
annotation.subtitle = @"The best park in New York City!";
[mapView addAnnotation:annotation];


// Set the map view's delegate
mapView.delegate = self;


// Allow the map view to display the user's location
mapView.showsUserLocation = NO;

}
```

Comment: Can you please help me in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52809975/when-ever-i-click-on-paypal-it-show-an-alert-service-unavailable

Comment: @RKios - give the moment , I wil check and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/4.1.1/Classes/MGLMapView.html), you'll find that `mapView.showsUserLocation = false` should do the trick.

Comment: If I do this then I can't able to get the current location @Geru

Comment: @RKios - then what you want to try, you want to remove or else

Comment: I just want to fetch current location without that blue dot

Comment: @RKios - then do like : disable your `mapView.showsUserLocation = NO;` and use corelocation framework for fetch the user location.

Comment: Then you should still be using this option and use a CoreLocationManager of your own to receive locations. I personally dislike the map box location manager, as you can't really configure it. You should not be relying on the user location from mapbox.