# When ever I click on PayPal it show an alert "service Unavailable"

Tags: ios, paypal

I am using PayPal payment gate way when ever I click on my it shows alert and payment is not successful I have attached a ScreenShot please let me know what I did wrong.[image: Click Here]

And my response is below

```
Error: {
category = Application;
errorId = 503;
message = "service unavailable";
severity = Error;
```

}

Comment: *overused* card number -  r u used the same card in all times, try with another card

Comment: can you print the full error log what you get on console

Comment: can you provide the response JSON

Comment: @Anbu.karthik Updated please check it

Comment: if you are tried in the alternate card also you get the same result or else.

Comment: Check my code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52757749/paypal-live-always-returns-error-in-objective-c

Comment: Not navigating to PayPal page bro..

Comment: is not a code issue.

Comment: @Anbu.karthik Found Anything